# How to implement cordova push notifications in intel xdk?

Tags: cordova, push-notification, intel-xdk

I want to create android app that has push notification. I have been looking for tutorials but no matches. I use intel XDK cordova build. How to implement [https://github.com/hollyschinsky/PushNotificationSample30/] in the intel XDK? Anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

Normally it should be done with a plugin. You can try with this one: `com.notifications.push`. You can find the api documentation [here](https://github.com/appfeel/cordova-push-notifications#-plugin-api).

(you should place it in the projects page)

Comment: Hi Miquel! thank you for replying. I will try your suggestion, but if I have trouble would allow you to help me because I am only a beginner.

Comment: I'm not really an expert in XDK, but I'll try the best. There is a demo app for xdk with admob plugin (not the same but similar), you can download and explore it from here: https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-xdk, the process to integrate `com.notifications.push` should be the same